# CosmosDB Upsert gives status code 449 even when there is no conflict

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

A .NET 6 application Upserts documents to CosmosDB.

I get many debug messages (not all writes)

```
DocDBTrace Error: 0 : DocumentClientException with status code 449, message: Message: {"Errors":["Conflicting request to resource has been attempted. Retry to avoid conflicts."]}
```

the ids of the documents are Guid instances and there are no unique keys in the container (so no conflicts).

What could it be?

**EDIT**

partitionKey = id

```
//F#
    let write database container items = 
        let container = client.GetContainer(database, container)

        items 
        |> Seq.map (fun item -> container.UpsertItemAsync(item))
        |> Seq.toArray
        |> Task.WhenAll
```

Data sample

```
    {
        "RESPONSE": [
            {
                "IntradayTickResponse": {
                    "CorrelationID": "ESM2 Index:intraday",
                    "TimeReceived": "2022-05-05T01:19:38.338794Z",
                    "tickData": {
                        "eidData": null,
                        "tickData": [
                            {
                                "time": {
                                    "DayOfMonth": 5,
                                    "Hour": 0,
                                    "MicroSecond": 0,
                                    "MilliSecond": 0,
                                    "Minute": 37,
                                    "Month": 5,
                                    "NanoSecond": 0,
                                    "Parts": 2046,
                                    "PicoSecond": 0,
                                    "Second": 7,
                                    "TimezoneOffsetMinutes": 0,
                                    "Year": 2022
                                },
                                "type": "TRADE",
                                "value": 4292.5,
                                "size": 2,
                                "conditionCodes": "TSUM"
                            },
                            {
                                "time": {
                                    "DayOfMonth": 5,
                                    "Hour": 0,
                                    "MicroSecond": 0,
                                    "MilliSecond": 0,
                                    "Minute": 37,
                                    "Month": 5,
                                    "NanoSecond": 0,
                                    "Parts": 2046,
                                    "PicoSecond": 0,
                                    "Second": 19,
                                    "TimezoneOffsetMinutes": 0,
                                    "Year": 2022
                                },
                                "type": "TRADE",
                                "value": 4292.75,
                                "size": 2,
                                "conditionCodes": "TSUM"
                            },
                            {
                                "time": {
                                    "DayOfMonth": 5,
                                    "Hour": 0,
                                    "MicroSecond": 0,
                                    "MilliSecond": 0,
                                    "Minute": 37,
                                    "Month": 5,
                                    "NanoSecond": 0,
                                    "Parts": 2046,
                                    "PicoSecond": 0,
                                    "Second": 19,
                                    "TimezoneOffsetMinutes": 0,
                                    "Year": 2022
                                },
                                "type": "TRADE",
                                "value": 4292.75,
                                "size": 1,
                                "conditionCodes": "TSUM"
                            },
                            {
                                "time": {
                                    "DayOfMonth": 5,
                                    "Hour": 0,
                                    "MicroSecond": 0,
                                    "MilliSecond": 0,
                                    "Minute": 37,
                                    "Month": 5,
                                    "NanoSecond": 0,
                                    "Parts": 2046,
                                    "PicoSecond": 0,
                                    "Second": 19,
                                    "TimezoneOffsetMinutes": 0,
                                    "Year": 2022
                                },
                                "type": "TRADE",
                                "value": 4292.75,
                                "size": 1,
                                "conditionCodes": "TSUM"
                            },
                            {
                                "time": {
                                    "DayOfMonth": 5,
                                    "Hour": 0,
                                    "MicroSecond": 0,
                                    "MilliSecond": 0,
                                    "Minute": 37,
                                    "Month": 5,
                                    "NanoSecond": 0,
                                    "Parts": 2046,
                                    "PicoSecond": 0,
                                    "Second": 19,
                                    "TimezoneOffsetMinutes": 0,
                                    "Year": 2022
                                },
                                "type": "TRADE",
                                "value": 4292.75,
                                "size": 1,
                                "conditionCodes": "TSUM"
                            },
...

        "id": "87fdc18a-61f2-4c43-a7a8-2904b14e6596",
        "_rid": "maszAOGSZkYwAgAAAAAAAA==",
        "_self": "dbs/maszAA==/colls/maszAOGSZkY=/docs/maszAOGSZkYwAgAAAAAAAA==/",
        "_etag": "\"00000000-0000-0000-601e-3057eca901d8\"",
        "_attachments": "attachments/",
        "_ts": 1651713578
    }
```

Comment: Please edit to include more details, such as how the collection is set up (e.g. partitioning), sample data that you're trying to update, relevant code, etc. A bit difficult to know what's happening, with only an error message. Also, it's unclear whether it happens every time you upsert, or maybe *sometimes*...

Comment: @DavidMakogon Data is plain Dictionary<>

Comment: No, I mean, show actual JSON of what you're storing. I'm not talking about any data structures in code. And also - note that you should really tag this as F#, given your edit.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I don't agree with tagging F#. This is not an issue with F#, but with CosmosDB Upsert

Comment: This error occurs when there are multiple concurrent updates happening to the same item. If you're getting the error it means the SDK has already retried it and is now returning to you to retry. Best course of action is to implement your own retry with backoff within your client app. More details here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/conceptual-resilient-sdk-applications#http-449

Comment: @MarkBrown There is concurrency but not on the same item. In this case all items are new (so upsert->insert). Does 449 still apply?

Comment: Maybe try passing the id for the pk value in your upsert command.